# SSL on virtual hosts in NGINX

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am new to NGINX, i have a case where i need to call a website with two URLs, one running on HTTP & other on HTTPS. To test this, i have created a dummy site accessible through NGINX on port 8080, and two virtual hosts www.mytest1.local.com & www.mytest2.local.com, i need to access www.mytest1.local.com through https protocol only and www.mytest2.local.com through http protocol only. Here is the snap of nginx.conf file:-

```
http{
   server {
     listen 443;
     server_name www.mytest1.local.com;
     ssl on;
     ssl_certificate C:\\Users\\sinhasu\\Downloads\\nginx-1.8.0\\SSL\\server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key C:\\Users\\sinhasu\\Downloads\\nginx-1.8.0\\SSL\\server.key;
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }
 }

 server {
server_name www.mytest2.local.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
 }
}

server {
 listen 8080;
     location / {
    root C:\\Users\\sinhasu\\Downloads\\nginx-1.8.0\\testdoc;
 }
 }
```

}

But this configurations doesn't seems to be running fine, both these virtual hosts `www.mytest1.local.com` & `www.mytest2.local.com` is responding on `http` as well as `https` protocol while i expect mytest1 url to accept only `https` and mytest2 url to accept only `http protocol`.

Please let me know if i am missing something in the configuration part.

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what you wanted, the fact you also able to access http on 8080 is default behavior of nginx. The second server has no listen so it defaults to port 80, it might even default to 443 as well without specifying a listen directive.